# Android touch event handling on ListView, ScrollView and PagerView

Tags: android, user-interface, touch

I have a PagerView (something like Google+ tab-slider, so to speak) which has a List View inside. Each list item has a HorizontalScrollView which will be visible on the screen onLongClick on the list item.

My HorizontalScrollView does not seem to be receiving touches which I think is because of the PagerView.

I'm using a 3rd party view widget called ViewFlow to replicate that PagerView. Any ideas?

I'm taking a guess that it is due to view hierarchy ( PagerView > ListView > ListItem > ScrollView ). Since PagerView is essentially a HorizontalScrollView, I'm taking a stand that it's intercepting all the horizontal swipes before ScrollView can receive it. Anything that I can do to selectively intercept touch events? (e.g. Stopping PagerView from intercepting touch when the start point is within the ScrollView? )

Comment: I have also faced same problem. I came to know touch events are not supported over ScroollView.